# Something's adding www to my site

Tags: wordpress, url, .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-routing

I don't know why but if I type http://mysite.com/subsite it redirects me to http://www.mysite.com/subsite, the htaccess file is just the standard wordpress htaccess file, if I try to modify it to remove the www from the url it throws me a redirection error (since it removes the www corectly but then something adds the www again trapping it in an infinite loop). Does anyone know what could be doing this to my url?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the admin dashboard and goto Settings->General and then look for either "WordPress address (URL)" or "Site address (URL)". Whatever you have one of these set to is what is doing the URL rewriting. I forgot which one though.

Comment: Wow can't believe I missed this, thanks that was the problem!

Comment: Do note, this won't fix any URLs that are stored in the database with the WWW... (so you may find images, etc... still reference the www version of the site)..